# Overscrolling at the botton in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to ensure that there is a visual indication that the user is trying to scroll more to the bottom even though he has reached the end of the list in a LazyColumn.

This feature is available by default in XML layouts.

How do we implement this in Jetpack compose? For over scrolling at the top, I see that there is a [Swipe for Refresh](https://google.github.io/accompanist/swiperefresh/) equivalent. Is there a solution out there at present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With version 1.1.0-alpha04 for Jetpack compose, glad to see that a feature to show a visual indication that the user has reached the end of the list is built just like xml...